# SignalR Javascript Connectivity Issues

Tags: signalr

I have an Azure Function running in localhost which has a SignalR output binding as follows:

```
[FunctionName("FxAdoHttpTrigger")]
        public static async Task Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [SignalR(HubName = "AdoEvents")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
     
            await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    Target = "newMessage",
                    Arguments = new[] { data }
                });
        }
    }
```

The following Javascript is in a web app running on localhost:

```
connection.on("newMessage", (data) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = `${data}`;
    document.getElementById("messageList").appendChild(li);
});

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(start, 5000);
    }
};

connection.onclose(async () => {
    alert('onclose fired');
    //await start();
});

// Start the connection.
start();
```

The appSetting in the web app running locally is:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Values": {
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "Endpoint=https://XXXsignalr-jjjjj.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=secret;Version=1.0;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I consistently get "SignalR Connected" but no client connection shows up in the SignalR Live Trace. No matter what i change the connection string to, I always get success on connect.

Since the Azure Function is publishing to SignalR separately from the Web App, who only wants to read newMessage, I'm at a loss of what i am missing. Do I need a newMessage method in my /Hubs/AdoEvent hub? I have no methods in the hub:

```
   public class AdoHub : Hub
    {

    }
```

I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the settings in azure function serverless

[image]